# How to Kill window service when uninstalling?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an installer which installing window services. The code to start and stop window service is below:

```
<Component Id="cmp690F4EBE95710C864C32A36852D2EB2F" Guid="{F933F79A-F76B-45F9-A951-6AD31C77B180}">
        <File Id="fil61E48774FB18BBADEDCE4566002C9F54" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.APMrelease)\LiveServer.exe" Name="LiveServer.exe" DiskId="1">
          <firewall:FirewallException Id="LiveServer.exe" Name="LiveServer.exe" Description="LiveServer 2.0" Profile="all" IgnoreFailure="yes" Scope="any" />
        </File>
        <ServiceInstall Id="InstallLiveServerService" DisplayName=" LiveServer" Description="LiveServer 2.0" Name="LiveServer" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" ErrorControl="normal">
          <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart" SecondFailureActionType="restart" ThirdFailureActionType="restart" ResetPeriodInDays="4" />
          <!--<ServiceDependency Id="PostMaster" />-->
        </ServiceInstall>
        <ServiceControl Id="StopLiveServerService" Name="LiveServer" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
```

I am starting my service with custom action which is fine. But when uninstalling the installer, sometimes service get hang and unable to stop due to which uninstall fails. Is there any way to wait and then kill the service or any other workaround?

Comment: What does the MSI log file and the service logging mechanism say?

Comment: There is an issue in window service that was i am stopping

Comment: Is there any GAC-involvement here? (Global Assembly Cache). You obviously need to work out your service problem so that it reliably stops in a predictable fashion. Obvious I know, but anyway.

Comment: Is it because there is a related process that is running that needs killing first?  In which case, could you not schedule another CA to run before the StopServices action that runs: taskkill /im "yourprocess.exe" /f /t